# Right way to update deployments on Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

Currently, I'm updating the version of an image to be deployed using the `set image` command:

```
$ kubectl set image deployments myapp myapp=caarlos0/myapp:v2
```

And then I watch the changes with `rollout status`:

```
$ kubectl rollout status deployments myapp
```

The problems I found while doing it this way are:

- some times, it seems that a deployment is not triggered at all, and when I call `rollout status`, I get errors like this:

  ```
  $ kubectl rollout status deployments myapp
  Waiting for deployment spec update to be observed...
  error: timed out waiting for the condition
  ```
- The `rollout history` command show the `CHANGE-CAUSE` as `<none>`, and I can't find a way of making it show anything useful in there.

So, am I doing something wrong (or not in the best way)? How can I improve this workflow?

Comment: set image on a deployment is the correct (declarative) way to handle a rolling update. Could you clarify your environment? How did you provision the cluster to help troubleshot?

Comment: The cluster was provisioned with kops on AWS. Both client and server versions are 1.5.2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're doing the right thing. Within the [Updating a deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/deployments/#updating-a-deployment) documentation you'll find this:

> Note: a Deployment’s rollout is triggered if and only if the Deployment’s pod template (i.e. `.spec.template`) is changed, e.g. updating labels or container images of the template. Other updates, such as scaling the Deployment, will not trigger a rollout.

So running `$ kubectl set image deployments/app <image>` will only trigger a rollout if `<image>` is not already configured for your containers.

The change cause can be used to record the command which was used to trigger the rollout by appending the `--record` flag to your commands (see [Checking rollout history](https://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/deployments/#checking-rollout-history-of-a-deployment)).

Answer (score 0):

**Deployment is observed by the controlplane component Deployment controller, make sure kube-controller-manager is running. for example below controller-manager is not running so it will not rollout deployments.**

[image]

**once controller is up and running it will start rollout** example below

[image]