# Waiting for deployment spec update to be observed when get kubernetes deployment status

Tags: kubernetes

Today when I tried to use this command to get the kubernetes deployment rollout status, shows error like this:

```
> kubectl rollout status deployment/texhub-server-service -n reddwarf-pro
Waiting for deployment spec update to be observed...
```

the command stuck and will never end. I also tried to using this command to restart:

```
kubectl rollout restart deployment/texhub-server-service -n reddwarf-pro
```

still stuck when get status. I did not found this deployment was staying busy in console. why did this happen? what should I do to fixed this issue?

Comment: Feel free to update the status of the question. Let me know the answer below helps to resolve your issue? I am happy to help you if you have any further queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per **Garry Shutler’s** article written on [Kubernetes rollout stuck](https://gshutler.com/2018/11/kubernetes-rollout-stuck/);

> This seemed to put all replica set creation in limbo as other deployments also ended up stuck in a similar state.

> Wild speculation is that an in-memory lock was blocking the replica set creation and that killing the process broke the lock.

**Try removing old replica sets, it may help to start work again.**
You can achieve this using the command `kubectl delete rs <rs name\>`. Where rs name is the name of your ReplicaSet.

You can also refer to other causes for this error in [Failed Deployment](https://unofficial-kubernetes.readthedocs.io/en/latest/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#failed-deployment);

> 1. Insufficient quota
> 2. Readiness probe failures (ensure your liveness and readiness probes are correctly set)
> 3. Image pull errors
> 4. Insufficient permissions
> 5. Limit ranges
> 6. Application runtime misconfiguration

Comment: You can also refer to similar [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73389359)1 & [SO2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42561791), which may further help to resolve your issue.

Comment: I was misconfiguartion my kubelet and make it running into issue. fix the kubelet issue solve this problem.